# Cursor moving to starting position when trying add decimals in html input

Tags: html

I have a HTML element, `input type="number"`. When I'm trying to add a decimal after adding a number, the dot is removed and the cursor is moving to the start position and I'm able to add the decimal before the number. Can anyone explain why it is behaving like this and How can I fix this behavior?

Here's my HTML element in case of ref:

```html
<input class="form-control custom-form-control input-sm bg-color-report-select border-0 text-color-info" autocomplete="off" name="latitude" type="number">
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome Version 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: There isn't any issue with the code (at least of that you provided), I even tried it with no issue inserting the decimal point.